# How to theme the PAGE template for user account?

Tags: theming, routes

The user account page should have the title(name or username),user pic on the left, basic details like gender, city, state and country to the right. The local tasks tab should be available below those regions.

I tried page--user.tpl and page--user--profile.tpl. Doesn't work.

Am using drupal 7 with an adaptive sub theme and don't know PHP much.

Comment: Each time you create new tpl file. You have to clear the cache. The page--user.tpl is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the right template suggestion for user page which holds all user profile data then you should go with page--user--%.tpl.

Just imagine you want to remove the title on all user pages. removing it on page--user.tpl will remove it on all user pages like user/login, user/register, user/pass, etc.

Use page--user--%.tpl to do it only on user profile pages.

Checkout what i was able to do with mine. [image]

Answer (score 1):

it can be override with `user-profile.tpl.php` file.

> Default theme implementation to present all user profile data.
>
> This template is used when viewing a registered member's profile page,
>   e.g., example.com/user/123. 123 being the users ID.

[REF here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7)