# How do I theme the user profile page?

Tags: views, theming, users

What is the best / easiest way to theme the user profile page? I'm building a talk radio website and registered members will provide news articles publically avail. eventually there will be thousands of registered users.

I'm worried that I will figure out an answer that works but isn't correct and will force me to go back and rewrite later on.

I don't know if I should use views or just straight code the page-user.tpl - if I straight code,  what function gets the uid from the /user/xx url? if I use views how do I assign the view to the pages in /user/xx

For some reason I cannot find any complete info on this; either it's a great secret or I'm missing something really simple. thank you!

Comment: Though you have written many things here but still its not clear what you want to achieve, design or functionality. At one place you are asking about theming the profile page of user & ending with giving functionality such as user activity, info etc. Please clarify

Comment: I just want a basic user profile page that a registered user can customize with a avatar, bio, etc, displays a summary of their recent activity like any articles they've written and where unregistered visitors can search for and look at.  
  
I just don't know how I should take my first step and I'm worried that I'll find a way to make it work but it won't be the right way and I'll have to do a total rewrite once the user database gets bigger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to theme the PAGE template for user account?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65553/how-to-theme-the-page-template-for-user-account)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to use a combination of VIEWS and template overrides, hooks, css and custom PHP.

Comment: Could you summarize this a little bit?  This answer won't really help anyone else who reads it in the future.

Comment: in the end, Drupal 7 was so designer unfriendly I gave up on it. so while I figured some solutions to problems I ran into, drupal 7 turned out to be too complex for me to understand well enough to design the way I wanted. (I'm not a backend guy) however drupal 8 beta is stable enough and is very designer friendly so I'm working with it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) modules and optionally [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2).

You will add some fields to user account or to the user profile if you installed Profile2. Then enable the 'User profile template' page under `admin/structure/pages` and add a panel variant, select a layout and place the content or fields. If you have Profile2, then you need to add it as a relationship 'Profile2 from user' under the 'Contexts' menu of the panel page. I'm not going into details about how to use panels.

To display the summary of user's recent activity, you should setup a view with a contextual filter of user id, preferably a 'Content pane' display, then you need to place this content pane into you user panel.

It is not a great secret how to build a user profile page, but it's completely dependent of what you want to have. If you have any difficulties implementing the steps I wrote, you can update your question or post another more specific question.

Comment: I've heard panels slows down the site which is why I didn't give it much thought. Is there any truth to that?

Comment: If you use caching it is much better than core blocks.